# Spring data JDBC migrate to 2.1 - IdGeneration no such method

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to migrate from `1.1.3` to `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jdbc:2.1.0` to get PagingAndSorting.
Other dependencies which required updating in order to run my project was:

```
    ...
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.5.RELEASE"
    ...
     
    ...
    implementation("javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final")
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.1.5.Final")
    ...
```

My code compiles with new dependencies, I can run read/update queries (on postgresql) but when I try to save new entity I get following error:

```
2020-11-04 13:54:31.214 ERROR 5402 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect.getIdGeneration()Lorg/springframework/data/relational/core/dialect/IdGeneration;] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect.getIdGeneration()Lorg/springframework/data/relational/core/dialect/IdGeneration;
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.insert(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:126) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.executeInsertRoot(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:94) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:66) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.lambda$execute$0(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DefaultAggregateChange.forEachAction(DefaultAggregateChange.java:116) ~[spring-data-relational-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.store(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:339) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:149) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:60) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at simpl.backendservice.service.DynamicLinkService.saveNewDynamicLink(DynamicLinkService.kt:104) ~[main/:na]
    at simpl.backendservice.service.DynamicLinkService.createNewDynamicLink(DynamicLinkService.kt:78) ~[main/:na]
    at simpl.backendservice.service.DynamicLinkService.createDynamicLink(DynamicLinkService.kt:61) ~[main/:na]
```

According to: https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/20/migrating-to-spring-data-jdbc-2-0 Spring Data JDBC - Reference Documentation it should work by default with Postgres Dialect.

What might be the issue? If some kind of dependency mismatch how can I debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Following steps described here:
https://reflectoring.io/nosuchmethod/

I managed to fix it by running
 `./gradlew dependencies > dependencies.txt`

opening generated file and searching for org.springframework.data:spring-data-relational mentioned in my stacktrace. I found line below:

`|    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-relational:2.1.0 -> 2.0.5.RELEASE`

Finally I changed my dependency to:

`implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jdbc:2.0.5.RELEASE")`